# Netbeans Java GUI editor preview problems

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, layout-manager

I have been using netbeans GUI editor for some time now to design a Front-end GUI for an application I am designing, it is based on using a CardLayout and the image below should be displaying a simple login screen. However after I made some changes (i added a new panel) the whole thing has gone nuts! The image is skewed off the centre and half of the screen simply does not render. Any suggestions on causes of this or any fixes for it would be appreciated!

Feel free to ask for any additional info!

[image: This is what appears when I attempt to preview my design]

Comment: *"Any suggestions on causes of this"* The code used ... *"Feel free to ask for any additional info!"* Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you try and remove the new panel you have added? If I remember correctly `JPanels` are *invisible* the first time you add them, so it could be that the newly added `JPanel` is affecting your GUI in a manner you are not expecting.

Comment: just tried removing the most recently added panel, didnt fix anything, if I really drag out the window, and i mean really expand its size i can just see the buttons for login, but it never has done this before!!!

Comment: @AndrewThompson the code used is whatever netbeans generated, its not particularly friendly for programmer eyes, i was more hoping this is a common issue with netbeans gui...

Comment: its almost as though the alignment has completely changed for the mainPanel (which all the other cards/panels are contained within)

Comment: @MatthewPigram : Are you settings Bounds for the components yourself, seems to me that's the only thing that can cause such a behaviour, other then that nothing appears to me the cause. Else try to remake your project :( Without the code, it's hard to say what is causing concerns.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : For the last three days, SSCCE site is not working for me. Is it for everyone or I am the one facing issues with it ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw  My apologies.  I was having trouble bringing up another domain on the same server, but it seemed to be working ..if slowly.  I just tried a 3rd domain on the server and it came up like lightning.  The 4th (I have many domains!) is also very slow..  I'll raise a support ticket and get 'back to you'.

Comment: I already fixed this, but my comments appear to have been removed or something, anyways what caused this issue was that for some unknown reason netbeans decided to change a parameter for several of my frames messing up its default sizing which resulted in the image above. The parameter is found when click on the mainPanel (that is the parent of all the cards for the cardlayout), in the properties tab > layout > horizontal size & vertical size had been changed from "default" to numerical values. These were properties that I had never touched before, but had now changed

Comment: @nIcEcOw  Working for you now?  I've heard nothing back from the support, but the sites are now fine from here.  If you don't mind, get in contact with me be email - andrewthommo at gmail  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What caused this issue was that for some unknown reason netbeans decided to change a parameter for my main frame messing up its default sizing which resulted in the image above. The parameter is found when clicking on the mainPanel (that is the parent of all the cards for the cardlayout i was using), in the properties tab > layout > horizontal size & vertical size had been changed from "default" to numerical values. These were properties that I had never touched before, but had now changed.

Resetting the value to "default" solved the issue, just one of those weird things i guess

Comment: It's always tough to roll your head with the IDE, especially in situations like these, when they try to be extra intelligent :-)

Comment: yeh they can be painful at times, but all's well that ends well